# .NET Framework: How to make RichTextBox true read-only?

Tags: .net, richtextbox, readonly

Setting RichTextBox as “ReadOnly” doesn't prevent embedded objects (like equations) from being edited by double-clicking them. I could disable the control but then there is a gray background (can't be just changed with BackColor) and no way to scroll. I tried to override OnDoubleClick in a derived class but no success.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution! :) In a derived class:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0203) // WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the answer from Entrase was a good start.  Unfortunately, the control still allowed selecting text and deleting it.  I ended up using the following code:

```
Public Class ReadOnlyRichTextBox : Inherits Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

    Protected mOkayKeys As Windows.Forms.Keys() = {Windows.Forms.Keys.Up, Windows.Forms.Keys.Down, Windows.Forms.Keys.PageUp, Windows.Forms.Keys.PageDown}

    Private Sub ReadOnlyRichTextBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.Control And (e.KeyCode = Windows.Forms.Keys.C) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not mOkayKeys.Contains(e.KeyCode) Then e.Handled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadOnlyRichTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        e.Handled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadOnlyRichTextBox_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If e.Control And (e.KeyCode = Windows.Forms.Keys.C) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not mOkayKeys.Contains(e.KeyCode) Then e.Handled = True
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Windows.Forms.Message)
        If (m.Msg = &H203) Then ' WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK=0x0203
            ' Do nothing
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Just try setting Sellength to 0 on doubleclick. Isn't there a readonly/locked property?

Comment: No. It's going to process double click without mentioning the selection. And as I said “ReadOnly” property doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows

1)Set the RichTextBox property ReadOnly to true

2)Go to **Properties->Appearance->BackColor** and set color as **Window**

Comment: or just set the locked property to true